# How to store and retrieve an item in the Users collection?

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I am building a 2FA component to a simple Meteor app and would like to store the code I send a user, to eventually check against the code they submit.

To put it simply, I need to store a value in the user collection for the current user, then retrieve that value a bit later on.

I'd imagine this is a fairly simple task, but my lack of familiarity with MongoDB and Meteor is frustrating me. Any help or advice would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Meteor.users.update({_id: userId}, {$set: { key: value}}); // set value to key

Meteor.users.findOne(userId).key; // read value by key
```

Comment: I am trying to insert the sent code value to the corresponding current user ID, but this is not working:         Meteor.users.insert({_id: currentUserId}, {$set: { 'authCode': authCode}});
Thoughts? I am passing the current userID in to the server side method btw

Comment: Is this running on the server or client? Where are you getting currentUserId from?

Comment: This is running on the server. I get the currentUserId from the a client method and then pass it as an argument to the server side method (logged out the value to make sure it is getting passed). I definitely have the right user ID

Comment: You need to use update, not insert. For security purposes, you should use `this.userId` whenever you're in a method/publication on the server side. Otherwise someone could manually call the method and supply it any userId they wanted to.

Comment: Gotcha! Can I use update if the field does not yet exist? (In this case authCode)

Comment: You most certainly can.

Comment: Great! Everything works now and I replaced passing the userId with this.userId. Thank you for the help!